# MS SQL Server: Windows authentication works from a local account but not from an MS account

Tags: windows, login, sql-server

I use MS SQL Server Management Studio to work on a database using Windows authentication from my home Win64 laptop computer.

- If I log my laptop to a local Windows account ("LocalAag"), I can log into the SQL
  database with no problems.
- However, if I use my "connected" Microsoft account ("CloudAag", which is preferable to me for many reasons), I cannot login using Windows Authentication (but I can login using SQL Server authentication.

The reason is, as I understand it, that the SQL Server knows "LocalAag" but not "CloudAag" as an authorized login.

Now, I am wondering about the best strategy around this.

- shall I add "CloudAag" to the authorized logins in SqlServer?
- alternatively, I'd prefer to assign the same UserID to both "CloudAag" and "LocalAag". But I haven't found any way to change the UserID of a cloud-resident MS account.
- is there anything else that can be done to overcome this problem?

Answer (score 1):

In SQL Server you have logins and users. Logins just get you connected into the SQL Server, users are specific to each database and have their own database permissions.

Adding a login for the cloud user to the SQL Server is the correct way, you can then map it to the same user as your other account.

Login as the local account and open
**Management -> SQL Server Logs -> Current**

Find the line that shows your cloud user failing to login to get the specific spelling as the SQL Server see's it.

> Logon failed for user 'someuser'. Reason...

Add 'someuser' as a login. In properties of that login you have created you can use User Mapping to link it to a specific user.

Comment: regrettably, I cannot find any failed-login entry. The client says: "The target principal name is incorrect. Cannot generate SSPI context". I have read that this occurs when there is no trusted relationship between the client and the domain controller. Now, I don't have a domain controller in my setup. Plus, the login works from the same client if logged in with a local account.

Comment: Try using the Kerberos Configuration Manager https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=39046&WT.mc_id=soc-n-[TR]-loc-[Services]-[farukc]